# How to covert an array of type Float to Any in Julia?

Tags: list, julia

I would like to convert an array to a `python like list` in Julia.

To create an array of `type` `Any` one may initialize an empty array with this syntax `array = []`. However if I want to perform conversion, i.e. lets take an array of type `Array(Float64,1)` to type `Any`, what would be the correct approach?

Or If there are any alternate approaches to create a list in Julia?

My approach to create a function which takes an array and convert it to type any:

```
function list(x)
    x = convert(Any, x)
    return x
end

x_test = [0.19, 0.03, 0.27]
t1 = typeof(x_test)
println("type of x_test is: $t1")
x_test = list(x_test)
t2 = typeof(x_test)
println("type of x_test is: $t2")

Output:
type of x_test is: Array{Float64,1}
type of x_test is: Array{Float64,1}
```

Please suggest a method or solution to achieve this conversion task.

Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering, why do you want to do this? I really can't think of a use case where this would be a good idea.

Comment: @OscarSmith Thanks for the feedback, I wanted to append some values of not same dimension to the array and converting the one outlier into string and storing is the simplest option I could think of, But i agree it is not a good approach and will lead to lot of unnecessary overhead for the compiler.

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
julia> list(x) = Any[i for i ∈ x]
list (generic function with 1 method)

julia> list([0.19, 0.03, 0.25])
3-element Vector{Any}:
 0.19
 0.03
 0.25
```

But as Oscar says in his comments, why would you ever want to do that? It's true that Python performance often suffers because of a lack of type information, that doesn't mean Julia becomes "like Python" if you deliberately prevent the compiler from optimizing (it will become a lot slower though in almost all cases!)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and suggestion. Highly appreciate it!!! 
I wanted to append irregular arrays as a string to the array which already has some data. But I think you mentioned a valid point, this is not a good approach. I shall find an approach to avoid this methodology.

Comment: Note that depending on how irregular your data is, a small union might do the trick, eg `Array{Union{Float64, String}, 1}`

Answer (score 5):

The shortest form is `Vector{Any}(a)` as in code here:

```
julia> a=[1,2,3]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> Vector{Any}(a)
3-element Vector{Any}:
 1
 2
 3
```

However, if you want to be able to hold in a copy of `a` other elements such as `String`s you will be much more efficient by strictly telling that:

```
julia> b = Vector{Union{eltype(a),String}}(a)
3-element Vector{Union{Int64, String}}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> push!(b,"jan")
4-element Vector{Union{Int64, String}}:
 1
 2
 3
  "jan"
```

Comment: Actually, `Any[a...]` is shorter, but less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You were not far, you just need to convert to an ***array*** of `Any`:

```
julia> convert(Array{Any}, x_test)
3-element Vector{Any}:
 0.19
 0.03
 0.27
```

But as others have said, it's not a good idea to hide type information in general because it will just slow things down.